# QuickBooks connection error

Tags: quickbooks

Till recently I was able to connect to QB Online without any problem from my ASP.NET MVC web app. Suddenly I started getting an error that says "Development application can only subscribe to sandbox company. No Sandbox company found".

I do have an existing QB Online account that is associated with a dummy organization. I also see changes in the Intuit playground page where we test oAuth connection with QB online. My question is

Is there any change in procedure to connect to QB Online ? OR Is this a temporary error Intuit has introduced ? How do get this resolved soon ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Exactly the same code worked correctly 12 hours ago.

Comment: The same here. I think this post explains why this happened. https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/10/20/changes-to-ipp-app-tokens

Comment: QuickBooks is making some changes to the Ipp app tokens. See below link.
https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/10/20/changes-to-ipp-app-tokens

Answer (score 2):

QB changed their sandbox testing account. You have to create a new sandbox test account. Read these links for more info

https://developer.intuit.com/v2/blog/2014/10/24/intuit-developer-now-offers-quickbooks-sandboxes &
https://developer.intuit.com/v2/blog/2014/10/20/changes-to-ipp-app-tokens

Comment: If you want to keep connecting your old app to a production company, you have to log in to your developer account: https://developer.intuit.com/v2/ui#/app/dashboard click on your app and request production credentials.  You need to click on the big "Production" tab on the top and it will tell you what you need to do.  This involves verifying your email address and filling out a number of fields.  It's relatively painless.  I had to refresh the page at one point to get it to recognize that I had updated my profile.